# PHP random number storing in database issue

Tags: php, random

I am getting this weird kind of issue. The rand() function is generating random numbers correctly. But when it stores in the database the number is gone and only "8388607" number is stored in the MySQL database. I find this issue really strange.

```
$passcode=rand(); 
echo $passcode; //prints random number correctly

    $phone=$_GET['phone'];
    $email=$_GET['email'];
    $address=$_GET['address'];
    $documentid=$_GET['documentid'];

    $sql="insert into Transaction (date, amount, amountRs, passcode, isPaid, comment, clientid, receiverid) values ('$date','$amount','$amountRs','$passcode','no','$comment','$senderid[1]','$receiverid[1]')"; //stores "8388607" number in database
```

Comment: Did you checked that you have enough space for the column where you save the rand number?

Comment: Do a `show create table` and see what the data type is of Transaction.passcode.

Comment: Check the length of the column that stores the random number.

Comment: Also, can you echo $sql to the screen and see what the final INSERT statement looks like?

Comment: Check that your database as the correct data type for that field and as said before the length. This is so the db can store the data you require

Comment: Thank you all for help yes it is datatype issue and if fixed it.. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `8388607` is the maximum value of a `mediumint` (a 3-byte int), which is probably the type of your `passcode` column (you pass it a string, which MySQL converts back to a number...). Any number greater than `8388607` will be cropped to that value. On a 32-bit system only 1 random number every 256, on average, will not be cropped. On a 64-bit system that becomes one random number every 256^5...

Comment: Thanks Walter so much.. yes indeed it is datatype length issue. I scratched my forehead all this morning to sort this out. Life saver..